# Need a count of a certain date values in a column

Tags: mysql, date

My query should count dates in a date column that are:

1. occurrences of dates in the future 'no. upcoming'
2. occurrences of dates in past 90 days 'no. currently'
3. occurrences of dates older than 90 days 'no. older'

My query looks like this:

```
select u.user_id, count(m.theater_release_date < CURDATE()) as 'no. upcoming',
count(m.theater_release_date BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 90 DAY AND CURDATE()) as 'no.
currently', count(m.theater_release_date < CURDATE() - INTERVAL 90 DAY) as 'no. older'
from users u join movie m on m.movie_id = u.movie_id
group by u.user_id;
```

I get back counts in the date columns which are identical which obviously shows my query is useless.

```
 ---------+--------------+-----------------+------------+
| user_id | no. upcoming | no. currently   | no. older  |
+---------+--------------+-----------------+------------+
|       1 |          197 |             197 |        197 |
|    1929 |           11 |              11 |         11 |
|    2161 |           18 |              18 |         18 |
|    4385 |           10 |              10 |         10 |
|    4897 |            3 |               3 |          3 |
|    5737 |            6 |               6 |          6 |
|    6177 |            4 |               4 |          4 |
|    6289 |           12 |              12 |         12 |
```

Thanks Fabricator, your query brings back very similar results to mine, only now middle column all 0s.

```
+---------+--------------+---------------+-----------+
| user_id | no. upcoming | no. currently | no. older |
+---------+--------------+---------------+-----------+
|       1 |          197 |             0 |       197 | 
|    1929 |           11 |             0 |        11 |
|    2161 |           18 |             0 |        18 |
|    4385 |           10 |             0 |        10 |
|    4897 |            3 |             0 |         3 |
|    5737 |            6 |             0 |         6 |
|    6177 |            4 |             0 |         4 |
|    6289 |           12 |             0 |        12 |
|    7353 |            6 |             0 |         6 |
|    7417 |            1 |             0 |         1 |
|    7465 |           11 |             0 |        11 |
```

Comment: how about some data and the schema

Comment: The theater_release_date column in the movie table contains date datatypes, and is the only column I need to query besides user_ids.

Comment: yea so can you provide some data so we can see what the issue is? its like trying to fly blind without it.

Comment: Thanks John, just added slice of output. theater_release_date a date datatype column only column really significant here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL treats boolean values as integers, with true being 1 and false being 0.  So, you can just replace `count()` with `sum()`:

```
select u.user_id, sum(m.theater_release_date < CURDATE()) as `no. upcoming`,
       sum(m.theater_release_date BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 90 DAY AND CURDATE()) as `no. currently`,
       sum(m.theater_release_date < CURDATE() - INTERVAL 90 DAY) as `no. older`
from users u join
     movie m
     on m.movie_id = u.movie_id
group by u.user_id;
```

Note:  you should use single quotes only for string and date constants.  Use the backtick (in MySQL) to escape column aliases.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, but results the same as Fabricator. Could be correct but number of date values in theater_release_date column are varied looking at table directly, not the same across the constraints in query.

Comment: @aekandem . . . The obvious conclusion is that there are no release dates in the past 90 days.

Comment: Thank you Gordon, I am humbled and apologetic. I ran your query with parenthesis in wrong place. It worked like a charm. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

MySQL counts false values too, instead use `sum(if(condition,1,0))` like the following:

```
select u.user_id, sum(if(m.theater_release_date < CURDATE(),1,0)) as 'no. upcoming',
sum(if(m.theater_release_date BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 90 DAY AND CURDATE(),1,0)) as 'no.
currently', sum(if(m.theater_release_date < CURDATE() - INTERVAL 90 DAY,1,0)) as 'no. older'
from users u join movie m on m.movie_id = u.movie_id
group by u.user_id;
```